# what are the ways to get location of the device?

Tags: android, android-location

I created location manager service. With it, I want to catch instantaneous location change. I have created a service class and in it `LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {@Override public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {`. But, the listeners seem to have slow response. I am trying to improve the location service class. For this reason, what is the fastest, time, method and the other method(s) to catch the location change ?

Maybe, the question above is absurb to someone. In general I want to learn "what are the ways to get location of the device ?"

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user location using GPS and Internet Geolocation.
Here is the best tutorial that I found.
Work perfectly and get the location by the option that is turned on, and if none of that are enabled ask you to go to settings.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the location change on your own you should launch a thread that gets the location every certain period of time, bear in mind that GPS consumes lots of battery to the device.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Assigning GPS_PROVIDER to your location manager can take some time to get a fix.. If you don't require accuracy then assign NETWORK_PROVIDER to your LocationManger Like this

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mLocationListener);
```

Or you can switch between both depending on the time being taken....

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple class that can do this:

```
public class GPSPosition {

private double latitude;


private double longitude;


private String date;


public GPSPosition()
{
    LocationManager service = (LocationManager)Minipark.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isEnabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (isEnabled)
    {
        if (location != null)
        {

            this.longitude = location.getLongitude();
            this.latitude = location.getLatitude();

            Date locDate = new Date(location.getTime());
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("z yyyy.MM.dd. HH:mm:ss");
            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));
            String gmtTime = df.format(locDate);
            int position = gmtTime.indexOf(" ");
            gmtTime = "GMT+1" + gmtTime.substring(position, gmtTime.length());
            this.date = gmtTime; //GMT+1 time
        }
        else
        {
            this.longitude = -100000;
            this.latitude = -100000;
            this.date = "-100000";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        this.longitude = -100000;
        this.latitude = -100000;
        this.date = "-100000";

    }
}
```

Then I have a timer that instantiates the GPSPosition class every X seconds.